# Loading data into a designated row in EXCEL

Tags: c#, excel, ssis

I'm new to C# and with some help on web I have been able to load data from a SQL Server into EXCEL with individual sheets with corresponding data.

I should add that I am trying to accomplish this using a SSIS package "Script Task".  C# script.

Now I would like to insert the data in row A7 and not A1.  I've tried "insert [9442$A7:A7] (col...) VALUES ... but I get a syntax error.  Probably easy solution but I can seem to figure it out.

> ERROR: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: The Microsoft Access database
>   engine could not find the object '9442A7:A7'. Make sure the object
>   exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If
>   '9442 A7:A7' is not a local object, check your network connection or
>   contact the server administrator.

Here is my code relevant to creating and loading data into EXCEL.

Thanks in advance.

```
//Use OLE DB Connection and Create Excel Sheet
Excel_OLE_Con.ConnectionString = connstring;
Excel_OLE_Con.Open();
Excel_OLE_Cmd.Connection = Excel_OLE_Con;
Excel_OLE_Cmd.CommandText = "Create table [" + ColumnValue + "] (" + TableColumns + ")";
Excel_OLE_Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


//Write Data to Excel Sheet from DataTable dynamically
foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
{
    String sqlCommandInsert = "";
    String sqlCommandValue = "";
    foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in table.Columns)
    {
        sqlCommandValue += dataColumn + "],[";
    }

    sqlCommandValue = "[" + sqlCommandValue.TrimEnd(',');
    sqlCommandValue = sqlCommandValue.Remove(sqlCommandValue.Length - 2);
    //sqlCommandValue = sqlCommandValue.Replace(",", " ");
    sqlCommandInsert = "INSERT into [" + ColumnValue + "A7:A7" + "] (" + sqlCommandValue + ") VALUES(";

    int columnCount = table.Columns.Count;
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        string columnvalues = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
        {
            int index = table.Rows.IndexOf(row); 
            columnvalues += "'" + table.Rows[index].ItemArray[i] + "',";   

        }
        columnvalues = columnvalues.TrimEnd(',');
        var command = sqlCommandInsert + columnvalues + ")";
        //MessageBox.Show(command);
        Excel_OLE_Cmd.CommandText = command;
        Excel_OLE_Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

}
Excel_OLE_Con.Close();
```

Comment: Is there already data in the Excel sheet, or are you creating a new one?

Comment: Creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Data Flow task for this, not a Script Task. Use a SQL Server data flow component to select your data, and map that result set into an Excel File Output data flow component.

If you want your data to start on A7 (which I assume to mean "the first column but on the seventh row"), I am 99% sure that you can set a property on the Excel File Output component to use 6 rows as "header rows" - this will start your data on the 7th row.